# Exporting Python Output into CSV or Text File (Beginner)

Tags: python

I have created 5 functions that return a value. This value is later printed.
e.g.

```
print(randomnumbers(x))
```

output:

```
Number 1: 10
Number 2: 33
```

Would it be possible to export these results into a csv?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Please make sure to use the search function before asking, your question has been answered many times already on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the python `csv` module.

**Example**:

```
import csv
import random

data = [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(10)]

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

**`data.csv`**

```
9,3,7,4,1,3,7,8,1,3
```

Comment: Thank you! I dont know why some people were downvoting my question. I know it was a simple question. But I appreciate your response.

Comment: @OPM_OK, I'm glad it helped. Could you acept my answer?

Comment: Hey, just a follow up question. If I have a function that prints a bunch of variables. Is it possible to write the return of that function into  a file?

Comment: @OPM_OK Just replace the print of the function with a return!

Answer (score 2):

To write to a file you need to open it and then just send text to it:

```
data = [randomnumbers(x) for x in range(10)] # make a list of data

with open('FILENAME.csv','w') as f: # open the file, if it exists overwrite it, if it doesn't create it.
    for dataLine in data: # iterate through all the data
       f.write(dataLine) # write data line to the open file 
# with closes file automatically on exiting block
```

The csv library contains useful functions for reading and writing csv files, but I usually just use a line like:

```
dataStr = ','.join(data)
```

which will make all the elements in data into a string that is deliminated by the character in the quotes (here a comma for a csv).